# Django: Items not adding into the cart

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I've this function  in cart/views.py. If no cart exists, it does create a new cart once you try to add an item. But if I go into admin and look into the cart, there are no items. I think it's got something to do with cart/views.py the 'if product:' part. It is not saving the item against the cart id.

What do I change to make it work?

cart/views.py

```
def cart(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'cart/view_cart.html'
    try:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id'] #try to get cart id from the session
    except:
        cart_id = False
    if cart_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
    else:
        cart = False
    return render(request, template, context)

def update_cart(request, id): #adds item in cart
    try:
        product = Product.object.get(id=id)
    except:
        product = False
    try:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        cart_id = False
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id


    if product:
        new_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product)
        if created:
            new_item.cart = cart
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'cart item added')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')
```

single.html (where I click to add item)

```
    {% block content %}

    <a href ='{% url "update_cart" product.id %}'>Add to Cart</a>
    <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
    {% for i in images %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ i.image }}" width='500';/>

    {% endfor %}
```

cart/models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, default=0, decimal_places=2)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class CartItem(models.Model): #Creates items in the cart

    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart) 
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product) 
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return "%s" % (self.product.title)
```

cart/urls.py

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = patterns('cart.views',
        url(r'^$', 'cart', name="cart"),
        url(r'^update_cart/(?P<id>.*)', 'update_cart', name="update_cart"),
    )
```

Comment: Can you print the values "new_item.id" and "created"?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `cart` view. You make a bunch of tries and excepts and then just return an empty context (?) . Why is that for?

Comment: @KishorPawar not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but I tried both below but nothing came up         
    print new_item.id
    print created

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I think you're on to something. Previously I had this eror - 

ValueError at /cart/update_cart/2
The view cart.views.update_cart didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Where is this empty context? Or how/what in my code made it so?

Comment: Can you get anything printed above/below "if product" ?
even your name?

Comment: I tried with 
if product:
  print "abc"
  print cart.id

with no result

Comment: So I guess you got your hint.

Comment: @KishorPawar Now i tried 
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
  cart = Cart()
  cart.save()
  request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
  print "abc"

If I deleted current carts from admin, click add to cart, then it prints abc

Comment: Victor, you got it working?

Comment: Not yet. I think the issue is product keeps coming through as False everytime a cart is created, which is why its not added into the cart. But I can't figure out why it is not picking up the id